# How to add amazon app details store to this app?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play, google-play-games, amazon-appstore

while reskinig an app for amazon app store the amazon section in (PTModelGeneralSettings.0.attributes.xml) he amazon app store section is empty as you see:-
[image]

unlike the google play and apple store sections here:-
[image]

Please help me what i should do ?